# Laravel Policy Id Obfuscation

Tags: laravel

com/jenssegers/optimus id obfuscation.
It works fine but in the policy it doesn't works well when I implement it.

If I remove the policy it works fine.
My ProductPolicy

```
  public function view(User $user, Product $product)
    {

        return true;
    }
```

My ProductController

```
 public function show(Product $product, Request $request)
    {

        return response()->json([
            'product' => $this->product->where('id', $request->id)->relTable()->first()
        ]);
    }
```

My guess is that laravel automatically search for the id which is not the real one and there is no record on it. Then it will give an error `No query results for model App\Model\Product`. Is there a way to prevent this?

PS: If I useD the real id it works fine...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding), Laravel will search for a Product with key and will pass that model instance to `show` method of your controller. If you don't want this, then change `show` method to something like this:

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your model so that laravel will manually resolve the id.

```
 //Id obfuscation should be resolveManually
    public function resolveRouteBinding($value)
    {
       return $this->where('id', $this->optimus()->encode($value) )->first() ?? abort(404);
    }
```